# Amazon S3 integration with Sitecore 9.3 Media library files

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on the integration of Amazon S3 integration with Sitecore 9.3 Media library files. I am new to Amazon S3 integration and searched the implementation with Sitecore. I didn't find anything. Can someone provide the steps for integration then it would be helpful?

Comment: https://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.in/2016/04/how-to-upload-your-media-to-amazon-s3.html

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat - I just take a look at the above blog. But in that blog Sitecore integration was not there.

Comment: IMO, this would be a good starting point and replacing the Azure library with the Amazon S3 one - https://github.com/aweber1/Sitecore.Media.AzureBlobStorage

Comment: @BalaSM - Could you please take a look into it? - https://github.com/mikaelnet/sitecore-blob-storage